# MongoDB: how to select an empty-key subdocument?

Tags: json, mongodb, string

Ahoy! I'm having a very funny issue with MongoDB and, possibly more in general, with JSON. Basically, I accidentally created some MongoDB documents whose subdocuments contain an empty key, e.g. (I stripped `ObjectID`s to make the code look nicer):

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."), 
    "stats" : 
        { 
            "violations" : 0, 
            "cost" : 170, 
        }, 
    "parameters" : 
        { 
            "" : "../instances/comp/comp20.ectt", 
            "repetition" : 29, 
            "time" : 600000 
        }, 
    "batch" : ObjectId("..."), 
    "system" : "Linux 3.5.0-27-generic", 
    "host" : "host3", 
    "date_started" : ISODate("2013-05-14T16:46:46.788Z"), 
    "date_stopped" : ISODate("2013-05-14T16:56:48.483Z"), 
    "copy" : false
}
```

Of course the problem is line:

```
"" : "../instances/comp/comp20.ectt"
```

since I cannot get back the value of the field. If I query using:

```
db.experiments.find({"batch": ObjectId("...")}, { "parameters.": 1 })
```

what I get is the full content of the `parameters` subdocument. My guess is that `.` is probably ignored if followed by an empty selector. From the [JSON](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) specification (15.12.*) it looks like empty keys are allowed. Do you have any ideas about how to solve that?

Is that a known behavior? Is there a use for that?

**Update** I tried to `$rename` the field, but that won't work, for the same reasons. Keys that end with `.` are not allowed.

**Update** filed [issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9693) on MongoDB issue tracker.

Thanks,
Tommaso

Answer (score 2):

I have this same problem.  You can select your sub-documents with something like this:

```
db.foo.find({"parameters.":{$exists:true}})
```

The dot at the end of "parameters" tells Mongo to look for an empty key in that sub-document.  This works for me with Mongo 2.4.x.

Empty keys are not well supported by Mongo, I don't think they are officially supported, but you can insert data with them. So you shouldn't be using them and should find the place in your system where these keys are inserted and eliminate it.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the code and this does not currently seem possible for the reasons you mention. Since it is allowed to create documents with zero length field names I would consider this a bug. You can report it here : https://jira.mongodb.org

By the way, ironically you can query on it :

```
> db.c.save({a:{"":1}})
> db.c.save({a:{"":2}})
> db.c.find({"a.":1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("519349da6bd8a34a4985520a"), "a" : { "" : 1 } }
```

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to be sure before filing an issue.

Comment: Alright. Post a link to the issue here so people can vote on it if they run into the same problem. Thanks!